# seleniumのStaleElementReferenceExceptiontエラーの対処方法ご教授ください

Tags: python, selenium

#### 質問

下記コードを実行したときにStaleElementReferenceExceptionになります。
最初は出ていませんでしたがほぼ100%表示されるようになりました。

#### 試した内容

- sleepで待ち時間を設定　ダメでした
- x_pathの要素を配列にいれてfor文に入れる ダメでした

  ```
  for w in dd:
      ddd.append(w)
  ```

初心者なのでやり方がおかしいかもしれません…
対処方法教えていただけるとありがたいです。

---

下記がコードの一部とエラー内容です。

#### コード

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\wakar\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get(url)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div/nav/ul/li[5]").click()

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/main/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/form/input").send_keys(code)

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/main/div[2]/div/div/section/div[1]/form/button").click()

for i in range(click_times):
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loading']/td/div/a").click()

ddd = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/main/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")

    
for date in ddd:
    print(date)
    date_tmp_tmp = date.text
    date_tmp = date_tmp_tmp.split(' ',1)
    if re.compile('[0-9]{2}'+'/'+'[0-9]{2}').search(date_tmp[0]):
        date_h.append(date_tmp[0])
```

#### エラー内容

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_34836/1239864608.py in <module>
     56 for date in ddd:
     57     print(date)
---> 58     date_tmp_tmp = date.text
     59     date_tmp = date_tmp_tmp.split(' ',1)
     60     if re.compile('[0-9]{2}'+'/'+'[0-9]{2}').search(date_tmp[0]):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in text(self)
     75     def text(self) -> str:
     76         """The text of the element."""
---> 77         return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
     78 
     79     def click(self) -> None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py in _execute(self, command, params)
    708             params = {}
    709         params['id'] = self._id
--> 710         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
    711 
    712     def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    423         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    424         if response:
--> 425             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    426             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    427                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    245                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    246             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 247         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    248 
    249     def _value_or_default(self, obj: Mapping[_KT, _VT], key: _KT, default: _VT) -> _VT:

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.127)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x004F9943+2595139]
    Ordinal0 [0x0048C9F1+2148849]
    Ordinal0 [0x00384528+1066280]
    Ordinal0 [0x00386E04+1076740]
    Ordinal0 [0x00386CBE+1076414]
    Ordinal0 [0x00386F50+1077072]
    Ordinal0 [0x003AC920+1231136]
    Ordinal0 [0x003CB9EC+1358316]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A7474+1209460]
    Ordinal0 [0x003CBC04+1358852]
    Ordinal0 [0x003DBAF2+1424114]
    Ordinal0 [0x003CB806+1357830]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A6086+1204358]
    Ordinal0 [0x003A6F96+1208214]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0069B232+1658114]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0075312C+2411516]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0058F261+560433]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0058E366+556598]
    Ordinal0 [0x0049286B+2173035]
    Ordinal0 [0x004975F8+2192888]
    Ordinal0 [0x004976E5+2193125]
    Ordinal0 [0x004A11FC+2232828]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75F96739+25]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x772A8E7F+1215]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x772A8E4D+1165]
```

Answer (score 1):

### 更新

tryで例外を無視するのはどうでしょうか。

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

for date in ddd:
    try:
        print(date)
        date_tmp_tmp = date.text
        date_tmp = date_tmp_tmp.split(' ',1)
        if re.compile('[0-9]{2}'+'/'+'[0-9]{2}').search(date_tmp[0]):
            date_h.append(date_tmp[0])
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        continue
```

---

### 解決しなかった回答

以下の部分を変更したらどうでしょうか。「#」をつけた行が変更した行です。

```
ddd = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='container']/main/div[2]/div/div/section/div[2]/table/tbody/tr")

ddd_text = [date.text for date in ddd] #

for date in ddd_text:                  #
    print(date)
    date_tmp_tmp = date                #
    date_tmp = date_tmp_tmp.split(' ',1)
    if re.compile('[0-9]{2}'+'/'+'[0-9]{2}').search(date_tmp[0]):
        date_h.append(date_tmp[0])
```

Comment: ありがとうございます

やってみましたが
まだ同じエラーが出ます…

Comment: tryで実施したらエラーはかずできるようになりました！
ありがとうございます